# Shrink windows server 2008 software raid

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid, raid5

I have a windows server 2008 with 5*2TB disks in a windows server software raid 5.  I want to shrink the volume down to 3 disks and use the other two disks elsewhere but can't find a guide on how to proceed.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed here? Just taking disks offline seems a bit harsh and as far as I can see there is no resize option.

Answer (score 2):

There is no resize/shrink procedure.  Your only choice is to backup, recreate your RAID volume and restore.